# No X11 DISPLAY variable was set. while uploading product image in aws server then that time it causes this error

Tags: amazon-web-services, variables, x11, display

No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it in spring-mvc application. while uploading  product image in aws server then that time it causes this error

I deployed the spring-mvc application in aws server. I uploading the product information and product images in aws server. but i facing the above exception.
my images stored location in usr/share/tomcat7/Project/productfiles/images path. product information is stored in database but while uploading the images causes this issue.

In my project create category, i submitting the category details it will store in db. but incase of product image uploading causing this exception

Answer (score 0):

1. Give the permission to root user in aws and upload the image in aws.
2. In my case i am generating a thumbnail for the image. I used the Graphics2D class for generating the thumbnail. but its work in local. Graphics2D class rising the headless exception. it's works fine in local server. when in i deploy the app in aws-server No X 11 Display variable was set. so i changed the code Thumbnailator code(It is a third party)